# How do I upload my iPhone pictures/videos to my Windows Vista PC?

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, photos, windows

I found a page in iTunes that appears to allow me to sync pictures from my PC to my iPhone, but I can't see any obvious way to upload pictures taken on my iPhone4. How do I do this?

What about videos I've taken on my iPhone?

Just in case any of these matter:
iPhone 4.0.1
iTunes 9.2.0.61
Windows Vista Home Premium with SP2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just do it by connecting the iPhone, then opening the folder..

1. attach device, open it in explorer
2. open "Internal Storage" on device
3. open "DCIM" folder
4. open "800AAAAAA" (?) folder
5. drag and drop pictures and files from device to somewhere else on my computer

[image]

Answer (score 3):

See [iOS: Importing personal photos and videos from iOS devices to your computer](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4083):

> 1) Connect your iOS device to the computer. If the AutoPlay window appears, click "Import Pictures and Videos using Windows", then skip to step 4.
>
> [image: autoplay pic]
>
> 2) Choose **Start** > **Computer**.
>
> 3) Right-click the logo for your device and click **Import pictures and videos**.
>   Click the Import Settings link.

iPhone will present itself to as a camera to the computer, so you can just use the built in camera software on your computer to import your photos. Just go into My Computer, and your iPhone should show up there.

See also [TS3195 iOS: Unable to import photos to computer](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts3195)

Answer (score 0):

Use [DiskAid](http://www.digidna.net/diskaid). It runs on both Mac and PC. (I believe there is even a free trial period for this application.)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to move a few photos, just send them by email, then do with them what you want when you get them on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the classic way thru file system browsing :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use the Camera Upload on [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/help/289/en)

The pictures will be on Dropbox on the iPhone and will then sync to the other computers